# Importing all Material UI Icons at once using asterix

Tags: reactjs, next.js, import, material-ui, icons

I am trying to import all MUI Icons at once for a dynamic icon component.

I have tried importing using asterix, but I always get an error. The component works when importing a single Icon, but as mentioned it doesnt work when importing the icons with an asterix.

**Code**:

```
import * as Icons from '@mui/icons-material';
import { ListItemIcon } from '@mui/material';

const DynamicListItemIcon = (props) => {
  const { iconName } = props;
  const IconComponent = Icons[iconName];
  return (
    <ListItemIcon>
      <IconComponent />
    </ListItemIcon>
  )
};

export default DynamicListItemIcon;
```

**Error**: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `DynamicListItemIcon`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue! I was using the wrong iconName.

For example: TableRowsIcon has to be TableRows for the component to work.